# How do I perform a mathematical equation on a specific cell in csv using pandas or csv?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to take a value, say 40 in cell row 4, column 5. Then I take 40, add 50 to it, then in cell row 4 column 5 it says 90.
I was trying to do it this way:

```
equations_reader = pd.read_csv("bank.csv")
equations_reader.to_csv(index=False)
add_e_trial = equations_reader.loc[1, bank_indexer_addbalance] = reciever_amount
```

bank_indexer_addbalance is the row number.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your story with us... Good luck.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and expected output, along with what problems you faced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I have understood well.. Anyway try something like:

```
equations_reader.loc[1, bank_indexer_addbalance] += reciever_amount
```

This will **add** `reciever_amount` in `equations_reader.loc[1, bank_indexer_addbalance]`

Comment: Tried this, nothing happens.

Comment: Check whether `bank_indexer_addbalance` match with your column name. 
For example if that column is named `'col5'` your variable have to be `bank_indexer_addbalance = 'col5'`